# Materialize e Slider em Angular2

Tags: angular, materialize

tudo bem?
Agora a dúvida é pra quem está acostumado a usar o materialize, mais precisamente o componente Slider que tem no menu Javascript/Media. Ele não inicia. Instalei o angular2-materialize seguindo todos os passos para a instalação com angular-cli. Mesmo assim ainda tive que comentar a //import "materialize-css"; na main.ts e não adianta adicionar as linhas

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Que dá erro 404.
Alguém já conseguiu resolver essas questões?

Abraços

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No angular cli nao se adiciona os estilo ao index, tem de ir ao ficheiro angular-cli.json e em :

```
"styles": ["../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css"]
```

e no scripts:

```
    "scripts": [
  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
  "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js"
],
```

Não se esquece de instalar por npm:
*npm i angular2-materialize*